# Update Matrix According to Array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I know that the title of the questions seems a bit odd but the answer I'm looking for is about this title. Lets say I have array of arrays and want to update it according to another arrays elements. For example;

array of arrays;

```
var arrayOfArrays =    [
                            [
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                            ],
                            [
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                                [false, false, false, false],
                            ]

    ]
```

and I have another array like

```
var elementArray = ["0-7-3","2-10-0","2-11-0","2-12-1"]
```

Is there any shortcut to update array of arrays according the elements in the second array like update 7th array of 0th array's 3rd column to true.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to toggle the element, or always `true` it even if it is already true?

Comment: It will not be true after I'm done. Just gonna create another arrays of array for each time I open the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split out the index and use it on your large array.

```
var elementArray = ["0-7-3","2-10-0","2-11-0","2-12-1"];
for(var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++){
  var idx = elementArray[i].split('-');
  arrayOfArrays[idx[0]][idx[1]][idx[2]] = true;
}
```

Comment: I'll try your solution, thanks for quick response. I'll update question according the result.

Answer (score 1):

I was not the first answer, and IrkenInvader's is nearly identical, mine just has some error checking in it which was needed within your example.

```js
var arrayOfArrays = [
  [
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
  ],
  [
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
    [false, false, false, false],
  ]
];
var elementArray = ["0-7-3", "2-10-0", "2-11-0", "2-12-1"];
for (var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
  var keys = elementArray[i].split('-');
  if (keys.length == 3 &&
    typeof arrayOfArrays[keys[0]] != 'undefined' &&
    typeof arrayOfArrays[keys[0]][keys[1]] != 'undefined' &&
    typeof arrayOfArrays[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] != 'undefined'
  ) {
    arrayOfArrays[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = true;
  }
}
console.log(arrayOfArrays);
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/trex005/kzbq9xL0/1

If you want to toggle instead of always changing the element to true, change

```
arrayOfArrays[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = true;
```

to

```
arrayOfArrays[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = !arrayOfArrays[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]];
```

Comment: Your solutions is also nice. I can find another place to make use of it thanks.